# Shortcut OR-chain applied on list

Tags: python, list

I'd like to do something like this:

```
x = f(a[0]) or f(a[1]) or f(a[2]) or f(a[3]) or …
```

with a given list `a` and a given function `f`.  Unlike the built-in `any` function I need to get the first value of the list which is considered to be true; so for `0 or "foo" or 3.2` I need to get `"foo"`, not just `True`.

Of course, I could write a small function like

```
def returnFirst(f, a):
  for i in a:
    v = f(i)
    if v:
      return v
  return False

x = returnFirst(f, a)
```

but that's probably not the nicest solution, for reasons also given in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534256/python-find-first-element-in-a-sequence-that-matches-a-predicate?lq=1).  As I mention this other thread, I could of course use code based on the 
solution given there, e.g.

```
x = next((f(x) for x in a if f(x)), False)
```

But I don't see a simple way to circumvent the doubled calling of `f` then.

Is there any simple solution I am missing or just don't know?  Something like an

```
OR((f(x) for x in a))
```

maybe?

I tried to find other questions concerning this, but searching for keywords like `or` is a bit problematic in SO, so maybe I just didn't find something appropriate.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with `returnFirst`.  It's encapsulated, in one place.  Not creating a utility function that you need that doesn't exist because people won't use it is trying to optimize someone else's workflow. I disagree that it's tasteless.   A small dose of documentation can fix the problem entirely.

Comment: duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077307/why-is-there-no-firstiterable-built-in-function-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm now using this:

```
x = next((v for v in (f(x) for x in a) if v), False)
```

It's a working idiom without doubling the call of `f` and without introducing a hacky local, but it still is not very readable (especially if `x`, `f`, `a`, and `v` are longer than one letter).

I'd be happy to hear of a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
next((x for y in a for x in (f(y),) if x),False)
```

Comment: Ah, beat me to the punch.  Does next return `False` if nothing's there, or `None`?  Might want to add the default value (`s/if x/if x, False/`)

Comment: Yeah, I don't really like those abuses of generators for having "local variables" in apprehensions etc.  But it works, right.  Upvote.

Comment: @Alfe: Agreed, I think using the separate function is clearer.