# python how can return first value = true in a list?

Tags: python

like this:
if list is `['', 'a', 'b']` return `'a'`
if list is `['', '', '']` return `''`
if list is `['a', 'b', 'c']` return `a`
is any method in python to do this?
I mean don't need I write function myself
I want a built-in method like `var a = b || c` in `javascript`

Comment: Also possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18208730/shortcut-or-chain-applied-on-list , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077307/why-is-there-no-firstiterable-built-in-function-in-python , etc.

Answer (score 12):

Obvious way is to use a generator expression

```
>>> next(x for x in ['a', 'b', 'c'] if x)
'a'
>>> next(x for x in ['', 'b', 'c'] if x)
'b'
```

But - all False raises an exception instead of `''`

```
>>> next(x for x in ['', '', ''] if x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

You can fix that by providing a default to `next` like this

```
>>> next((x for x in ['', '', ''] if x), '')
''
```

Answer (score 4):

Straight from the [`itertools` recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes), the Python endorsed solution (if you're on Py2, replace `filter` with `itertools.ifilter` or it won't short circuit properly):

```
def first_true(iterable, default=False, pred=None):
    """Returns the first true value in the iterable.

    If no true value is found, returns *default*

    If *pred* is not None, returns the first item
    for which pred(item) is true.

    """
    # first_true([a,b,c], x) --> a or b or c or x
    # first_true([a,b], x, f) --> a if f(a) else b if f(b) else x
    return next(filter(pred, iterable), default)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an unusual way using `max`.

```
>>> max(['a', 'b', 'c'], key=bool)
'a'
>>> max(['', 'b', 'c'], key=bool)
'b'
>>> max(['', '', ''], key=bool)
''
```

Downside is that it doesn't short circuit

Comment: `key=bool` would work as well (with `max`, I mean, not `min`-- but the same general idea)

Comment: @DSM, too cool for school :)

Comment: Yeah, as I edited to clarify, you'd need to do `max` instead.

Answer (score 1):

> I want a built-in method like var a = b || c in javascript

Python's `or` works pretty much the exact same way, so if you would write this in Javascript as

```
result = arr[0] || arr[1] || arr[2];
```

Then you could do the following in Python:

```
result = l[0] or l[1] or l[2]
```